# how to solve two equal symbolic equations in matlab

Tags: matlab, symbols, symbolic-math

I define a symbol something like that

```
VA = sym('VA');
VB = sym('VB');
```

after some calculations, i get

```
VB = somenumbers*VA + someother numbers;
```

then , I got this result's backup and keep `VBbackup`

and again after some calculations VB becomes different number with respect to VA
So , I get two equations as shown

Actually what I meant is ;

```
VB = 6*VA + 3;
VBbackup = 8*VA + 2;
```

How can I get the value of `VA` ?

Comment: Do you know the values of `VB` and `VBackup`?

Comment: VB=VBackup so 2 equations with 2 unknowns

Comment: WNot sure I follow. `VA=(VB-3)/6` and `VA=(VBackup-2)/8`?